# Doctrine mapping a class that doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I just re-installed Symfony2 and Doctrine.
It's brand new.

Now I generate an entity (called account), put some simple annotation and then want to update my schema. And then:

```
 [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]               
 Class 'NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Entity\Nathan' does not exist
```

But I don't have no class called Nathan (ok it's my firstname).Not anywhere in any bundle I currently have. I've had one like that but in another Symfony2 install.

Now when I create one entity named "Nathan" it works, but then it creates a schema that is not related.

Now my question is where doctrine can store "ghosts" entities ? I have tried to clear all the caches of doctrine & Symfony2 but it does not change anything.

Comment: Did you clear the cache by hand or true the console. If you've only done it trough the console please try removing the map manually. The "ghost" entities (originaly called proxies) are located in "app\cache\dev\doctrine\orm\Proxies" or for your production environement "app\cache\prod\doctrine\orm\Proxies".

Comment: thank you but I actually have nothing inside this folder. I even tried to delete it and recreate, but... It make sense though, I've never had this entity inside this symfony installation

Comment: An advise is to search for the "Nathan" string inside your IDE. Maybe you have writen it and forgot it ;)

Comment: JFC I had a repository class... at least this subject made me understand the proxies.

Answer (score 9):

i had the same problem, i solved this issue after adding autoloading-line to my composer.json:

`{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "",
        "symfony/yaml": ""
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "config/yml/"}, // here stay my yml-schema files
        "psr-0": {"": "Entity/"} // my generated entity-files
    }
}`

after editing file, just execute "composer update" in youre project path, the autoloader-classes will be regenerated with the new autoloader-path. 
then you can generate entity-model files or do anything else..
hope this help!

Comment: what if I'm using psr4 ?

Answer (score 0):

change

`"psr-0": { "": "Entity/" } // my generated entity-files`

to

`"psr-0": { "": "src/" } // my generated entity-files`